# Indexing List from right

Tags: list, kotlin

In Python, the index -1 is the first element from the right in a list.
How can the last nth element of a list be retrieved in Kotlin in the most idiomatic way? To write an extension for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dey already provided a solution for querying negative indexes, however I think you were looking for an extension function to query lists using both positive and negative indexes and using brackets. This is what you can do:

Extension functions cannot replace existing methods in classes. Since the [getter operator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/get.html) (which is the one that allows you to use brackets as in your example) already exists in the List class, you won't be able to create an extension like that. However, you can create a new extension method with the same behaviour:

```
fun <E> List<E>.gett(index: Int): E = if (index < 0) {
    this[size + index]
} else {
    this[index]
}

@Test
fun testGett(){
    val list = (0..10).toList()
    assertEquals(10, list.gett(-1))
    assertEquals(0, list.gett(-11))
    assertEquals(1, list.gett(1))
}

@Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException::class)
fun testException(){
    (0..10).toList().gett(-12)
}
```

If you really want to have your own implementation using the brackets, you need to create your own list class (by extending List interface) and override the **get operator function**.

(For the sake of clarity, I'm extending from ArrayList, so I don't need to implement other members)

```
class MyList<E> : ArrayList<E>() {
    override operator fun get(index: Int): E = if (index < 0) {
        super.get(size + index)
    } else {
        super.get(index)
    }
}

@Test
fun testMyList(){
    val list = MyList<Int>().apply {
        add(1);add(2);add(3)
    }
    assertEquals(3, list[-1])
    assertEquals(1, list[-3])
    assertEquals(2, list[1])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is no beautiful way to do this. I think, the best you can do is this (all code snippets contain function implementation and example to get the last element):

```
fun List.last(int n) = get(size() - n)
list.last(1)
```

But now last elements are indexed from 1 (more or less like in python). If you want to index from 0, you need to subtract additional 1:

```
fun List.last(int n) = get(size() - n - 1)
list.last(0)
```

Or if you want to use indexes like in python, you need to add n:

```
fun List.last(int n) = get(size() + n)
list.last(-1)
```

Comment: Isn't this off by one? Looks like `list.last(0)` will be out of bounds.

Comment: Yes, that's true - but I wanted to do this as in python, when last element is -1. I'm adding a note to answer

Comment: If you want to use -1, then it should be `size() + n`, not `size() - n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`last`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html).

For example

```
println(listOf(1, 2, 3).last()) // outputs: 3
```

Comment: I need the last nth Element, so that is not enough for me :/

Comment: @Morinator you changed your question after I answered your original question

Comment: Yes, because from your answer made me notice that it wasn't formulated very clearly.